# Styling ng-content in angular 2

Tags: angular, styles, ng-content

I am trying to style this ng-content in template.html:
`<ng-content select="span.blue-label.button-content"></ng-content>`

template css:

```
:host ::ng-deep .button-content.blue-label {
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: .1px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: none;
 color: blue;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

and in main component:

```
<gs-component>
        <span class="blue-label button-content">{{product.price}}</span>
    </gs-component>
```

it works fine in stackblitz but in my app it's ignoring it

Answer (score 1):

`:host` - If we want to style the host element of the component itself, we need the special :host pseudo-class selector.

`::ng-deep` - If we want our component styles to cascade to all child elements of a component.

`:host ::ng-deep` - But not to any other element on the page, we can currently do so using by combining the :host with the ::ng-deep selector.

Depending where your css code is at I am thinking that it's not hitting `gs-component` rather the host of it.

Ty to avoid `ng-deep` it's deprecated and for good reason as it can have adverse effects. `ng-deep` doesn't seem needed (but then again, I don't see rest of your code...).

Try to add this to `style.css`. So we only target spans of gs-component where it has class blue-label. If for some reason styles are still not applied better approach would be to use `!important` at the end of the style.

```css
gs-component > span.blue-label {
 cursor: pointer !important;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: .1px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: none;
 color: blue;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

But mind if I ask, why aren't you just adding the css code to the css stylesheet of component `gs-component` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks it works but i want add this css in template.css to reuse it in other components

Comment: Then just use selector `.blue-label {}` in `style.css` without `gs-component > span`. And if necessary add `!important`. Then class `.blue-label` will be available throughout the app. I don't know what is the scope of your `template.css` but I guess you can add it there too.